# read function from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, input

I'm going to read some function from a Unicode text file in matlab and calculate there answer with my own variables. first i use `fopen` to read the text file, then what should i do to convert each line of that text file to a function? for example the `func.txt` contains:

> ```
> (x^2)-3y
> sin(x+z)+(y^6)
> ```

and i need to write an `m.file` which read `func.txt` and process that like this:

```
function func1[x,y] =  (x^2)-3y
function func2[x,y,z] =  sin(x+z)+(y^6)
```

Comment: Wait, you don't need to use the function, instead you just have to parse the file and write it in that way, right?. So the problem is mainly to get the number and the names of independent variables the functions have? If you plan to use the function in MATLAB, isn't the cyclic definition of inline functions accomplishing your task either ?

Comment: @Acorbe the function in the text file may change each time. i have to read their files and calculate the answer with the variables i have defined my self. for example i defined `x0 , y0 , z0`for independent variables. then i read the function in the text file and do my operation in a for loop;

Comment: IMHO, in this case, using `inline` is the best choice. You don't really need to manipulate `funct.txt` to evaluate the values of the functions it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preamble:** if your final aim is to use those functions in matlab (i.e. evaluate them for some values of `x,y,...`), I would rather suggest the following approach that looks more robust to me.

In principle, in fact, you *don't need* to manipulate the file `funct.txt` to evaluate the functions defined therein.

---

**First problem:** each line of your file `funct.txt` must define an [inline function](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/inline.html).

Say that the first function (i.e., the first line) of the file `funct.txt` has been copied into a string `str`,

```
    str = '(x^2)-3y',
```

you can obtain a function from it using the command `inline`:

```
    f1 = inline(str,'x','y');
```

which gives to you (matlab output)

```
    f1 =
 Inline function:
 f1(x,y) = (x^2)-3y.
```

Now you can use `f1` just calling it as `f1(x,y)`, for whatever values `x,y`.

**Second problem:** you have to parse your file `funct.txt` to obtain the strings `str` containing the definitions of your functions. That's easier, you may want to consider the function [`fgets`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html).

**Third problem:** the functions in `funct.txt` may depend on 2,3 (or more?) independent variables. As far as I know there is no easy way to parse the string to discover it. Thus, you may want to define each inline function as depending on all your independent variables, i.e.

```
  f1 = inline('(x^2)-3y','x','y','z');
```

the variable `z` will play no active role, by the way. Nonetheless, you need to specify a third *dummy* parameter when you call `f1`.

Comment: I'm going to try what you suggest. AND do you know anything about how to use `str2func`

Comment: [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) allows another type of abstraction, i.e. to obtain an handle to a function using the function name. To use it here, you would need something like `f1 = str2func('@(x,y,z)(x^2)-3y');`. This would require an intermediate manipulation of your strings.